# How to search for rows within 2 date intervals using Dataset.Tables.Select method?

Tags: c#, database, ms-access, dataset, datarow

I have a database table "Leave".
Its primary key is "LeaveNo".
The other fields in the database include "LeaveDate", "EmpID" , "EmpName" , etc

I want to use the dataset.tables["Leave"].Select() method to acquire only the leaves the employee has made in a single month.

The best way I figured was to use two intervals i.e mm/01/2012 and mm/31/2012 
(I know some months have 30 days)

My current code is this and it does not work:

This was just a test code...

```
        string moreThan = DateTime.Now.Month.ToString() + "01" + DateTime.Now.Year.ToString();
        string lessThan = DateTime.Now.Month.ToString() + "31" + DateTime.Now.Year.ToString();

        leavesthisMonth = LeaveDS.Tables["Leave"].Select("EmpID='" + txt_EmpID.Text + "' AND LeaveDate <= '" + "#" + lessThan + "#" + "'" + "AND LeaveDate >= '" + "#" + moreThan + "#" + "'");
```

Can someone help me with this ???

Answer (score 2):

Working with DataSets and DataTables means that you are not bound (or anyway no more) to a database or specific SQL dialect.

The syntax used with the DataTable.Select() method is documented on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression.aspx).

For dates (obviously if the column type is REALLY DateTime) is used a syntax similar to MS Access (# delimited), so you can write:

```
var rows = dt.Select("LeaveDate > #2013-01-01#");
```

Is important to **NOT** use quotes (as in @Waqas code):

```
var rows = dt.Select("LeaveDate > '#2013-01-01#'");   // ERROR
```

because results in: System.FormatException: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

My advice is to use the **yyyy-MM-dd** format because is culture invariant by design.

A good way to build strings with a specific syntax is to use String.Format (or any variants) for clarity reasons, and let the DateTime type do all the specific date maths.

```
int month = 10;

var begin = new DateTime(DateTime.Today.Year,month,1); // first day of a month
var end = begin.AddMonths(1); // first day next month 

var format = "LeaveDate >= #{0:yyyy-MM-dd}# AND LeaveDate < #{1:yyyy-MM-dd}#";

var condition = String.Format(format,begin,end);

rows = dt.Select(condition);
```

Answer (score 1):

Notice your operator `<= LeaveDate and >= LeaveDate`

The operator it should be like `>= LeaveDate and <= LeaveDate`

The *`LeaveDate`* it should be like `LeaveDate.ToString("dd MMM yyyy")` or `LeaveDate.ToString("dd/mm/yyyy")`

```
leavesthisMonth = LeaveDS.Tables["Leave"].Select("EmpID='" + txt_EmpID.Text + "' AND (LeaveDate >= #" + lessThan + "# AND LeaveDate <= #" + moreThan + "#)");
```

Comment: Can you please give me the whole code 
I'm new to the whole thing and I got the code by looking over the internet...
Also please tell me why do I have to convert the datetime into string eventhough the field in my database has datetime type. ???

Comment: in C# we need to Convert the `int`, `DateTime` and etc. `toString` for a reason, http://www.dotnetperls.com/tostring

Comment: In MS Access, the date delimiter is #, not ', it is generally best to ensure the date is unambiguous, or it will be usually be interpreted as US.

Comment: I used the new code and got this error message 
Cannot perform '<=' operation on System.DateTime and System.String.

Comment: @WaqasAli try see the actual `Date` format for msaccess and let me know, i will to modify my answer.

Comment: I changed the order ie. dd/mm/yy 
still the same error.
Can you write a small module 
I will execute it on form load 
and see whether it works ??

Comment: Trust me on this, use year, month, day. There is a big difference between format applied to dates in a table and what the date actually holds. All dates are stored as numbers, so you just need what Access will understand.

Comment: Oh got it, such a silly mistake 
The module worked perfectly once i added "/" in the strings and then converted the string into datetime. 
Then I replaced the parameters in the .select method with the datetime ones .
Worked like a charm

Comment: @WaqasAli, sir Remou say that your `LeaveDate` DateType it must be _`Date`_ for msAccess

Comment: I think that wouldn't be fair but still okay

Comment: @WaqasAli you can edit your question as what you have found for correction from your question :)

Answer (score 0):

You could make the whole thing a lot easier by using Date() in the SQL:

```
 WHERE Month(LeaveDate)=Month(Date()) AND Year(LeaveDate)=Year(Date())
```

That removes all the date handling to MS Access and avoids a lot of problem.